# how to display int as two digit in java me

Tags: java, java-me

For some reason in Java ME I can't use `String.format()`, so what is the best way to achieve a `%2d` format in Java ME with an `int`? I read that the modulo operator can be used as a trick to achieve this, but how is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

How difficult the code is depends on your assumptions on the values the integer can take.

If `int x` is in the range [0, 100) (best case):

```
String result = (x < 10 ? "0" : "") + x;
```

Answer (score 1):

*modulo can be used as a trick to achieve this*

For non-negative *value*, `value%10` would give you the first digit, `(value/10)%10` would give second, `(value/100)%10` would give third digit etc